# Complex numbers of degree less than or equal to 2 over rational numbers

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

Im trying to figure out which complex numbers have degree $\leq$2 over $\mathbb{Q}$ and then figure out which have degree $\leq$2 over $\mathbb{R}$.

For the first question, I know that it is at least $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ and the second is at least $\mathbb{R}(i)$ but i can't seem to prove whether I'm missing anything or not

Comment: Quadratic extensions of a field $F$ (of characteristic $≠ 2$) are always of the form $F(\sqrt a)$ with $a \in F$ (and $\sqrt a \not \in F$).

Comment: does that imply that since $i\in\mathbb{C}$, the answer is $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-1})$?

Comment: Every complex number $a+bi$ is of degree $\le 2$ over the reals. You can find an explicit polynomial of degree $\le 2$ of which it is a root.

Comment: You also have $\Bbb Q(\sqrt 2)$, $\Bbb Q(\sqrt 7)$, and so on. Notice also that extensions of degree $1$ are trivial.

Comment: Andre, that follows from $(x-a)^2+b^2$ right? and watson, does that mean that $\mathbb{Q}(i)\cup \{\sqrt{a}:a\in\mathbb{Q}\}$?

Answer (score 2):

The complex numbers of degree $≤2$ over $\Bbb Q$ are exactly of the form $a+b\sqrt d$ for some $d \in \Bbb Q$ (if $d<0$, then $\sqrt d = i\sqrt{|d|}$).

Let $z=x+iy$ be a complex number of degree $≤2$ over $\Bbb Q$, and let $P(X)=X^2+pX+q$ its minimal polynomial. Solving $P(z)=0$ yields $$z=\frac{-p \pm \sqrt d}{2}, \quad d=p^2-4q \in \Bbb Q,$$
so that $z$ is of the form $a+b\sqrt d$ as desired.

Reciprocally, if $z=a+b\sqrt d$, then $z$ is of degree $≤2$ over the rational numbers, because $(z-a)^2=db^2$ so that $z$ is a root of $X^2-2aX+a^2-db^2$.

---

All the complex numbers are of degree $≤2$ over $\Bbb R$: if $z=a+bi$, then $(X-z)(X-\bar z) = X^2-2a+a^2+b^2$ is a real polynomial having $z$ as root. Then the minimal polynomial of $z$ has degree $≤2=\text{deg}(P)$.